# Python - requests get is failing with connection error but url works fine

Tags: python, rest, python-requests, weblogic

I am connecting weblogic server through api to collect the status of servers. the REST apis are going through fine if I try from browser and i am able to get the response.

I wrote a python script to make these REST api calls. but they are failing with connection failure.

> Error - requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.',
>   error(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote
>   host'))

There is no proxy setup in our environment.

this is the sample code

> ```
> url = 'http://' + host + ':' + port + url
> response = requests.get(url, auth=(username, password),
>                          headers=headers)
>
> # Check for HTTP codes other than 200
> if response.status_code != 200:
>     print('Status:', response.status_code, 'Headers:', response.headers, 'Error Response:', response.json())
> ```

I am not able to identify if this issue is from weblogic or from the script I wrote since I am always able to get response properly every time if I hit from browser.

Weblogic apis I am trying to get - http://localhost:7001/management/wls/latest/deployments

has anyone faced this scenario and able to solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: What's the initial value of `url`, and what's the final value?

Comment: The initial URL will contain the component route e.g.,  - /management/wls/latest/deployments . I am attaching host and port to that to build final URL as http://localhost:7001/management/wls/latest/deployments